# AD LDS configuration

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

I am currently developing an application that uses LDAP to add/read users to the active directory. For that, I have installed AD LDS on my local machine, but it seems to be filled with data from my workplace.

How do I 'clear' the Active Directory Sites and Services in AD LDS and fill it up with my own data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites and services is connecting to your organization's AD by default. If you right click in the top left of the MMC, you can use Change Domain Controller and then plug in your local instance (server:port) in the listbox on the bottom.